# Go run greeter_server/main.go

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I don't know how to access the server which is listent at [::]:50051

BELOW IS THE DISCRIPTION

```
$ go run greeter_client/main.go
Greeting: Hello world
```

I'm a new bie to the world of programming!

I try the below code on the same laptop listening from aforementioned server!

```
$ go run greeter_client/main.go
Greeting: Hello world
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you following the [Go Quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/)? `greeter_server` runs (by default) on port `50051` (see [line](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/12b8fb52a18c8a1667dde7a4f8087ecdd2abbeaf/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go#L34)) and `greeter_client` connects (by default) to port `50051` (see [line](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/12b8fb52a18c8a1667dde7a4f8087ecdd2abbeaf/examples/helloworld/greeter_client/main.go#L38).

Comment: So, if you run `greeter_server` in one terminal and `greeter_client` in another terminal on the **same** host (and no other process is bound to `50051`), the sample should just work.

Comment: Yes I'm following the Go Quick start! So on same host: from another terminal! Still didn't work! I don't know if I have to call the server from a particular directory?

Comment: Please edit your question add some more details showing what you do and what happens (including error messages). This will help us help you. To be clear, if you're seeing `Greeting: Hello world` when you `go run greeter_client/main.go` it **is** working.

Comment: My fault! It letter work! From a different terminal! Under the same example hello world directory!

Comment: Yah it worked! Under the same example/helloworld directory using the client command.       $ go run greeter_server/main.go. Thank you Daz.

Comment: I'm pleased to read that you got it working! You're welcome.